# How many possible passwords are there for 8-100 characters?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Requirements/Restrictions: Minimum of 8. Maximum of 100. At least 1 letter from the latin alphabet (capitalisation doesn’t matter—g is same as G, 26 letters), at least 1 number (0-9, 10 numbers) and it **may** also include special characters (33 special characters/symbols).

Here’s what I did:

$26 \times 10 \times 69^6 \times 70^{92} = \\1574300283675196381393274771319731729003339411333808462\\
6274484198008813380319383474217713060000000000000000000\\
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000$

One of the characters must be a letter (26), then another must be a number ($26 \times 10$), there are 6 spots left to reach the minimum, all the possible characters added together is $69 (= 33 + 26 + 10)$ so ($26 \times 10 \times 69^6$). Then there are 92 spots left, since they don’t have to be filled, the user has the option of leaving it blank, so now instead of 69 options, it’s 70. Hence, ($26 \times 10 \times 69^6 \times 70^{92}$).

I would appreciate it if someone confirmed whether I am correct or not.

Thank you :)

Comment: Not quite because if you leave one space blank you can't then have a character after it

Comment: More than that, you also messed up the "*at least one ___*" bit too.  Starting your count with $26\times 10\times \cdots$ is very specifically only counting passwords whose *first* character is very specifically a letter and whose second character is very specifically a number.  You miss counting scenarios where neither of the first two characters are letters or numbers but who have a letter and a number appearing in later positions in the password.

Comment: hmmm...i didn't think it would matter where the letter or number is. As long as its in the password, doing x26 and x10 should work.

Comment: Compare that to the problem of finding a length $2$ password with at least one letter from $\{a,b,c\}$ and at least one number from $\{1,2\}$.  By your logic you would have $3\times 2 = 6$ passwords, but those are only the passwords $a1,a2,b1,b2,c1,c2$ and you missed the passwords $1a,1b,1c,2a,2b,2c$

Comment: ahhhh. yes i see. thank you. Then i think it would be 26! x 10!?

Comment: Why factorial?!  Don't just throw symbols in randomly without stopping to think about what they represent.  No.  $26!\times 10!$ is the number of length $36$ passwords whose first $26$ characters are letters each letter occurring exactly once without repetition followed by $10$ digits each digit of which occurring exactly once without repetition.

Comment: To correctly account for the "at least one ___" conditions, you should use inclusion-exclusion.  Count the total number of passwords without such a condition.  Then, subtract the number of all those passwords who failed to have any letters.  Subtract the number of all those passwords who failed to have any digits.  Then, add back the number of those passwords who failed to have either letters or digits since we accidentally subtracted these twice before when we only wanted to subtract them once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

26 alphabet characters, 10 numeric characters, 33 special characters (including blank space, which can be placed anywhere) - that’s 69 total

For an *N*-length password:
If there were no “at least 1” conditions, you’d have $69^N$ posibilities.
Then, to satisfy “atleast 1 letter”, we need to remove all options without a letter: $(69-26)^N$. And to satisfy “at least 1 number”, we need to remove all options without a number: $(69-10)^N$.
But then we need to add back in all options without a number OR a letter, i.e., with only special characters (since we’ve removed those twice): $33^N$

So, for an *N*-length password, the number of possibilities is $69^N - 43^N - 59^N + 33^N$

So for the total you want the sum of each different possible length, i.e., your answer is $$\sum_{N=8}^{100}(69^N - 43^N - 59^N + 33^N)$$

Stick this in some code to calculate it nice and quickly, and you get 7784830887958863955006123907413479732322179460547538436324402442938556231147248052155742398941820197907332216822738647248662040228937662527224075073302550548119136634116724084874159040 $\approx 7.78 \times 10^{183}$ options.

Comment: oh sorry my bad, I meant Maximum of 100 characters, ill edit that in. Capitalisation doesn't matter, g is same as G. Thank you for your reply, ill edit the post now to make it clearer :)

Comment: just added something about blank spaces too

Comment: blank space is part of that 33 and its allowed anywhere in the password

Comment: Are you sure it's allowed at the end? That would be a very silly thing to do in reality...

Comment: for the sake of simplicity, in the example I am doing, it is allowed. I don't really know about reality though :)

Comment: See my comments above about the incorrectness of beginning the count with $26\times 10$.

Comment: Your attempt to fix the issue was incorrect.  Consider the example of counting how many passwords of length $5$ there are where every character must be an $A$ *who contains at least one $A$*.  It is a silly example, yes.  We can tell at sight immediately that there is only one such password: $AAAAA$.  By your logic though, there would be $5\times 1\times 1^4=5$ such passwords.  You are incorrectly applying significance to which of the positions was the "*designated*" position for a letter/digit.  Again, see my comments above... in particular my comment about inclusion-exclusion.